# nutch solrindex add 1 document

Tags: pdf, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I tried to add pdf using nutch mysql solrindex, but only one document was added.

The parsed data is large enough. What's the problem?

```
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 50 pages, 0 errors, 3.3 3 pages/s, 7994 6968 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
-activeThreads=0
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:      false
ParserJob: parsing all
Parsing http://www.adb.org/sites/default/files/cross-debarment-agreement.pdf
......
cilab@cilab:~/workspace-jupyter/#Members/JongYum/nutch/runtime/local$ bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/demo -allSolrIndexerJob: starting
Adding 1 documents
SolrIndexerJob: done.
```

Comment: Any reason why it should be more than one document?

Comment: I parsed several PDFs. But there is only one that is indexed at solr. I want all PDF files to be indexed.